# Manage Orderbook using TimeScale DB

Tags: timescaledb

I am working a crypto exchange having hundreds of trading pairs. All orders are stored in MongoDB. There's also "orderbook" table in MySQL that stores top 10 buy orders and top 10 sell orders of each trading pair. This table is streamed through socket for Front-end display.

The entire orderbook logic is written from scratch with following logic

1. When new order is placed, check it's price and compare, if price is there, add the quantity to existing order in table.
2. if price doesn't match but should be in top 10, then remove the last order and add this one.
3. substract quantity if order is executed or cancelled.

The problem starts when there is a market order and weird bugs pop up.

I have been a fan of TimeScale DB for OHLCV so far, and was wondering if TimeScale provides the orderbook creation and management module out of the box. I have checked their website, but couldn't find much information on this.

Is there any other way to achieve a fully accurate and performance centric orderbook management ?

Comment: TimescaleDB is for time-series data. Active order books are **not** time series data, so TimescaleDB is unlikely to provide any special support for this.